# Change pig schema

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to change a schema from:

```
describe JOINED_WITH_PARENT;
JOINED_WITH_PARENT: {ROWS_TUPLES::id: chararray,ROWS_TUPLES::url: chararray,ROWS_TUPLES::score: chararray,ROWS_TUPLES::parentId: chararray,ROWS_TUPLES::title: chararray,ROWS_TUPLES::body: chararray,GROUPED_PARENT_ID::group: chararray,GROUPED_PARENT_ID::ROWS_TUPLES: {(id: chararray,url: chararray,score: chararray,parentId: chararray,title: chararray,body: chararray)}}
```

To:

```
JOINED_WITH_PARENT: {id: chararray,url: chararray,:score: parentId: chararray,title: chararray,body: chararray,group: chararray, answers: {(id: chararray,url: chararray,score: chararray,parentId: chararray,title: chararray,body: chararray)}}
```

I was thinking of doing a foreach on JOINED_WITH_PARENT and attempted with the following, but the syntax does not seem to be correct. Am I on the right track ? Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
A = FOREACH JOINED_WITH_PARENT GENERATE 
   id as (id:chararray),
   score as (score:chararray),
   parentId as (parentId:chararray),
   title as (title:chararray),
   body as (body:chararray),
   group as (group:chararray),
   answers as tuple(chararray,chararray,chararray,chararray,chararray)GROUPED_PARENT_ID::ROWS_TUPLES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to project the fields you should't specify the type and as you project from a join need to specify the "source" relation, like this:

```
A = FOREACH JOINED_WITH_PARENT GENERATE 
   ROWS_TUPLES::id as id,
   ROWS_TUPLES::score as score,
   ...
   GROUPED_PARENT_ID::ROWS_TUPLES as answers;
```

Comment: a tiny observation: while ALWAYS mentioning the source relation is possible, it is not required. It's only really required when the field name exists in both sources.